# Where is this University website pulling its data from?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to create a discord bot that pulls in all the event data from the University's events page and sends it in a discord channel (using Python).

Here's the URL that I'm trying to scrape:
https://www.mmu.ac.uk/student-life/events/

I've been able to scrape it (using requests & bs4), but only the data that is loaded on the initial page load. Anything after that, I'm stumped on how to get.

How do I go about scraping the data that's displayed after the "view more events" button is clicked?

I've tried to look into the networks tab in developer tools, but I'm struggling to find anything of use.

Code so far:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Instantiating the bot
BOT_TOKEN = 'ABCDE'
CHANNEL_ID = 12345
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

#event handler that should be called when the bot is ready and connected to Discord.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is connected, online and working.")
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send("Hello! Work is underway on my project bot!")

  
#command that responds to '!hello'
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello!")


#command that takes in any number of integers and returns the result
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, *arr):
    result = 0
    for i in arr:
        result += int(i)

    await ctx.send(f"Result: {result}")


# This command sends a list of upcoming events at Manchester Metropolitan University to the channel.
# It fetches the events page of the MMU website, scrapes the relevant info (Title, date & location) using Beautiful Soup,
# and formats it into a string before sending it as a message. 
@bot.command()
async def scrape(ctx):
    url = 'https://www.mmu.ac.uk/student-life/events/'
    headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    event_list = soup.find('ul', class_='listing--events')
    event_items = event_list.find_all('li', class_='event-list__item')

    events = []
    for item in event_items:
        event_name = item.find('h3', class_='event-list__title').text.strip()
        event_date = item.find('p', class_='event-list__date-start').text.strip()
        event_location = item.find('p', class_='event-list__location').text.strip()
        events.append(f"{event_date}\n{event_name}\n{event_location}")

    await ctx.send("\n\n".join(events))

bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: The `requests` module does not understand Javascript.  You'll have to use some other way of fetching the page (such as Selenium) that does understand Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

To print all events from all pages you can use their API URL (it should be visible in Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab when you click on "View more events"):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = 'https://www.mmu.ac.uk/includes/classes/r-paging.php'

payload = {
    "type": "events",
    "category": "student-life|new-students",
    "limit": "15",
    "page": 1
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0',
}

while True:
    data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload, headers=headers).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data['content'], 'html.parser')

    for li in soup.select('li.event-list__item'):
        date_start = li.select_one('.event-list__date-start').text
        title = li.h3.text
        location = li.select_one('.event-list__location').text

        print(date_start)
        print(title)
        print(location)
        print('-'*80)

    if data.get('res') != 'success':
        break

    payload['page'] += 1
```

Prints:

```
...

Thursday, 18 May
Managing Stress Workshop
Online
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Monday, 22 May
Assertiveness Skills Workshop
Online
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tuesday, 30 May
Building Confidence Workshop
Online
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

This website is using XHR to fetch the data .
you can use request module to get details. Play with payload and increase the limit you will get the results . Also you can use loop to get multiple page with limit as constant .

1. type
2. category
3. limit
4. page

```py
    import requests
    
    url = "https://www.mmu.ac.uk/includes/classes/r-paging.php"
    
    payload = "type=events&category=student-life%7Cnew-students&limit=15&page=2"
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=rcrrr34t3u98nibn0dujne7b3a'
    }
    
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    
    print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.
What you need to do in this case is open the network tab in dev tools, click the button, and check what request it sends and where.

In this case, clicking the button sends a POST request to *https://www.mmu.ac.uk/includes/classes/r-paging.php*.
To get the data it sends back, you must mimic the request (the payload and some of the headers, possibly) in your code. This should return a response containing HTML with the information you need.
Good luck!